# Simplifying nested CASE expressions

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I'm currenty working on the project that has an sql expressions to do some calculations in the database as follows:

```
SELECT
  SUM( 
    CASE models.type
    WHEN 'type_1'
      THEN ( CASE models.attribute_id 
             WHEN other_models.other_attribute_id
               THEN ROUND(models.value * other_models.conversion, 2)
             ELSE
               models.value   
             END ) * -1
    WHEN 'type_2'
      THEN ( CASE models.attribute_id 
             WHEN other_models.other_attribute_id
               THEN ROUND(models.value * other_models.conversion, 2)
             ELSE
               models.value   
             END )
    END
  ) as value
```

This works well enough, but it seems bad to me to have the outer case expressions `THEN` clauses to be pretty much exactly the same apart from the `* -1`. Is there a way to express this so that the first case expression just gets multiplied by the second something along the lines of:

```
  SELECT
    SUM( 
      CASE models.attribute_id 
      WHEN other_models.other_attribute_id
        THEN ROUND(models.value * other_models.conversion, 2)
      ELSE
        models.value   
      END * (CASE models.type
             WHEN 'type_1'
               THEN -1
             WHEN 'type_2'
               THEN 1
             END)
    ) as value
```

Seems like something that would be possible to do, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Case _expressions_, not statements.

Comment: I've edited the question to fix this

Comment: Great! A case expression has a return value. A case statement (in a stored procedure) is just conditional execution of code.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to nest `case` *expressions*:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN models.type = 'type_1' AND models.attribute_id = other_models.other_attribute_id
                THEN - ROUND(models.value * 10)
                WHEN models.type = 'type_1'
                THEN - models.value   
                WHEN models.type = 'type_2' AND models.attribute_id = other_models.other_attribute_id
                THEN ROUND(models.value * 10)
                WHEN models.type = 'type_2'
                THEN models.value   
           END) as value
```

However, repeating all the logic seems unnecessary.  If you only have the two types, I would go for:

```
SELECT (models.value *
        (CASE WHEN models.attribute_id = other_models.other_attribute_id THEN 10 ELSE 1 END) *
        (CASE WHEN models.type = 'type_1' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)
       ) as value
```

These are only slightly more complicated if you have other types that you want to ignore.

I should also note that I don't recommending rounding *before* the aggregation, unless that is really what you intend.  If you want the result to be rounded, then round afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for the help, though in your second example isn't it missing the condition that determines if the the value is rounded? Which is necessary.

Comment: Also I think oversimplified my question, I've updated it to match what my actual code is like.

Comment: @user2320239 . . . Is rounding really desirable?  Usually it is not before doing a `sum()`.

Comment: Yes the rounding is needed, since this code is specifically being used to account for errors in rounding in other places in the system.

Comment: @user2320239 . . . In that case, you can nest the multiplication; I notice you already figured that out in another question.